# Mapped working directory was on failed drive, Source Control Explorer hangs

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, source-control-explorer

I had just done a check in, everything seemed fine. About 15 minutes later, the hard drive that the project was on on the local dev box failed completely. After sorting the issue out, I went to connect to my network-local TFS server and Source Control Explorer returns the following error:

---

```
Microsoft Visual Studio

Error

Could not find a part of the path 'I:\Programming\My Project\$tf'.
```

Source Control Explorer then hangs with the directory tree showing "Working..." under my project space. No options appear to remap, unmap, or reconnect and download the project.

What can I do to kick start SCE and get my project off of TFS again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by recreating the folder structure on another drive, sharing the folder on the network (right click folder, Sharing tab, share to everyone). Then I mapped that shared folder as a network drive using the original drive letter of the failed drive.

Source Control Explorer saw the "new" drive and folder path and offered to let me remove the mapping and map it to a new location.